# How do I declare Maybe of a mutable type in an non-pure native function in Frege?

Tags: frege

The native-gen tool generates the native declaration for the 
`showOpenDialog` method in `javafx.stage.FileChooser` like so

```
data FileChooser = mutable native javafx.stage.FileChooser where
 native showOpenDialog :: FileChooser -> Window -> IO File
```

Compiling leads to the message

```
Non pure native type File must be MutableIO
    File in IO actions.
```

Now setting

```
native showOpenDialog :: FileChooser -> Window -> MutableIO File
```

leads to

```
FileChooser.showOpenDialog has an illegal
    return type for a method that is not pure, perhaps ST s (MutableIO
    File) would work
```

but following the advice leads to first error message again.

The compiler accepts `IOMutable File` as return type, which makes sense
since it is an IO action that returns a mutable type.

If possible, the compiler error message should be adapted to avoid frustration on the user side.

However, in this special situation, the file can be null and so
the core type is not `File` but `Maybe File`.
But then just using `IOMutable (Maybe File)` leads to the rather surprising message

```
The type MutableIO (Maybe File) is illegal,
    Maybe File must be a native type.
```

Any advice on how to properly declare this type?

Comment: Note that the original message did tell you the correct solution: replace `File` with `MutableIO File`. Unfortunately, the line break appears in an unfortunate position. Anyway, the message did **not** tell you to remove the `IO`!

Comment: True, even though I did not even consider this as a possible meaning of the  message :-) Anyway, future readers of this post will profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code generated by `native-gen` is wrong because `File` has been [declared](https://github.com/Frege/frege-native-gen/blob/master/types.properties#L10) as `IO` in `native-gen` but File is actually defined as a stateful (not `IO`) native type as can be seen from [here](https://github.com/Frege/frege/blob/master/frege/java/IO.fr#L57).

`IOMutable` is defined as `type IOMutable d = IO (MutableIO d)`. 
For your case, the mutable native type (`MutableIO d`) can be null so the following should work:

```
data FileChooser = mutable native javafx.stage.FileChooser where
  native showOpenDialog :: FileChooser -> Window -> IO (Maybe (MutableIO File))
```

Comment: Perhaps the type of File should be changed. It is debatable, to say the least, whether the few pure functions justifiy it being only ST